# Format as code automatically when pressing `Ctrl+K` or clicking on { } at the begining of a line

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

Sometimes I just want to format (with `Ctrl K` or just pressing the button `{ }`) only one line.

I suggest that when placing the *caret* at the begining of a line and pressing `Ctrl+K`/`{ }`, the current line gets formated as code (either using ``` ` or with 4 spaces). Like:

```
//Code here
```

or

`//Code here`

instead of having:

`enter code here`//Code here

**Edit:**
This is how *commenting*, *indenting*, ... work on most of editors/IDEs