# Bug in <code> when the line starts with #

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I'm don't know if the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags are supposed to exhibit the same behavior.

Part of the reason I don't know is that I can't seem to find any documentation for the `<code>` tag.

Anyway, the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags exhibit a different behavior in a case where I would expect them to behave the same way. It appears that a line starting with `#include` is breaking the Markdown engine in the `<code>` block.

The following Markdown

```
<code>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) { exit(1); return 0; }
</code>
```

is rendered as:

## include

int main(void) { exit(1); return 0; }

while the following Markdown

```
<pre>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) { exit(1); return 0; }
</pre>
```

is rendered as:

```
#include 
int main(void) { exit(1); return 0; }
```

Answer (score 11):

`<code>` is pretty much a [semantic element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1). It just tells the browser "This is code".

`<pre>` (meaning "pre-formatted") is a block-level element, and as thus [disables Markdown parsing within that block](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html).

That said, why would you write that stuff by hand anyway and not just use Markdown's 4-space-indent codeblocks, like you did in your question here?

Comment: I want to paste a chunk of code from an external editor into the entry box, and I find it easiest to wrap it with `<code></code>`.  It seems to me that `<code>` blocks should be treated like markdown codeblocks.

Comment: @McKay.CPP: Just highlight the text and click the code button (or press Ctrl-K). Seems easier to me. And re *It seems to me that <code> blocks should be treated like markdown codeblocks.* -- we're certainly not going to redefine HTML.

Comment: @balpah re: *we're certainly not going to redefine HTML* -- funny.  That's exactly what markdown is already doing with the `<pre>` tag.  HTML tags are allowed in `<pre>` blocks, but not in markdown `<pre>` block.  As far as ease w/ Ctrl-K vs wrapping w/ tags - to each his own.  I still prefer wrapping with tags as it doesn't modify the text.  I was under the false impression that `<code>` gave markdown code-block like results.   The [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section on code spans gave me that impression.

Comment: just re-pinging with the right @ name since I cannot edit comments.

Comment: @McKay.CPP you don't need to include my name. You're commenting on my post, so I'll be notified regardless of who (or if) you @mention.