# Asking new users posting Python code to double-check their formatting

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-interface, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to either fix up code formatting or educate noobs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50910/easy-way-to-either-fix-up-code-formatting-or-educate-noobs)
>   [Could the Help be better? (code section)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127215/could-the-help-be-better-code-section)

As a frequent reader, answerer, and editor of Python questions, I find that by far, the most common error new users make is to "format" their code by simply indenting top-level lines (function definitions, class definitions, etc.) by four spaces. In c or java code, (for example) this is not a very big problem, because the beginnings and endings of code blocks are explicitly marked with `{` and `}`. If I want to fix the indentation, I can reconstruct the correct indentation by paying attention to braces.

But in Python, this can lead to code that is not only incomprehensible, but also *unfixable* by editors, because it is impossible to tell where a code block is supposed to end. Most of the time, it's possible to guess at the correct block structure, but even so, it's just a guess; and there's always the risk that in guessing, the editor might inadvertently fix the very problem the OP was asking about.

Would it be possible to send a special message to users with under 50 rep asking Python-tagged questions? Something like "Are you certain your code is indented correctly? Highlight your code and press Ctrl-K or the code formatting button (`{}`) above for correct formatting."

This might be too domain-specific to be a high priority. But it drives me nuts trying to comprehend malformed Python code all the time. (And it seems these users must not be getting the message described in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98433/160584), or they wouldn't be making this mistake.)

---

After seeing some reactions to this proposal, I believe I may not have fully explained what I think is happening. My hypothesis about why this mistake happens is as follows:

1. User pastes [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant code, using indentation of 4 spaces. User then looks at code preview and sees that indented code is formatted correctly, while unindented code is not.
2. User correctly surmises that the way to format a code block is to indent it by four spaces.
3. User does not look for any additional information, and so does not learn that there is an easy way to indent the code.
4. User lazily decides to indent *only* top-level lines, befouling Python blocks, and escaping any warning message about unformatted code -- because the code *is* formatted.

I did a lot of looking around; this question is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50910/easy-way-to-either-fix-up-code-formatting-or-educate-noobs), because it isn't really about code *formatting*, but is rather about code *indentation*. I'm seeking to fix a related, but subtly different problem. This code *is* correctly *formatted* by users who *are* concerned about formatting, but are lazy and think they've got it all figured out already. The result is not poorly *formatted* code, but poorly *indented* code. My somewhat irritable tone above notwithstanding, I deeply identify with these people, and want to help them.

It might be that there are other ways to help this problem. Perhaps the "How to Format" box should explicitly mention the ctrl-k shortcut; it doesn't right now, at least based on what I see to the right of this box as I type.

Comment: I guess the script checks for four-space indented lines directly adjacent to non-indented lines. Since the inner blocks in Python are indented, they won't have that after indenting the outermost level (`def` etc.).

Comment: [Use this.](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116)  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963

Comment: @senderle: If you find (what you think is) a better duplicate, you're allowed/encouraged to leave a comment or edit it in. But it's generally discouraged to *completely remove* the original question that this one was closed as a duplicate of. 5 people did agree that it *was* a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, OK, I understand. Thanks for putting them both up for me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't asked them to double check it, but a small and simple walkthrough over the coding formatting options should do the same. I'd really like to have a feature like this one applied for the first few questions of a new user.

Stackoverflow most important thing is the code, so it should be very very clear how to properly format it.

The first time I asked a question I didn't understood that the `{}` button could be applied to multiline code, and I find out the `Ctrl+K` shortcut only later on from a comment to another question. I used the `<code>` tag, but we all know that is not the best solution.

This is why I also think that a simple walkthrough on how to properly format the code could be extended to all the languages, hence be unrelated to any tag.

Comment: This is very helpful suggestion and as a new user, I was not aware of this option until now. However, I'm not sure if admins will be willing to do the extra work for a problem not many people complain about and possibly not many people will use. A simpler option might just be informing the user about the problems in formatting and telling them about the Ctrl+K option.

Comment: See [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87323/have-formatting-guide-include-reference-to-code-block-helpers-ctrlk-code-bl). (cc @fai)

Comment: I'm deferring my proposal in favor of [yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127215/177799) which you posted in a comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127189/160584).

Comment: @senderle: You touched a very important problem, bad formatted code is a plague. I hope it could be solved in a way or the other :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this isn't going to work.

The small subset of users who might heed the message you wish to show:

> Are you certain your code is indented correctly? Highlight your code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> or the code formatting button (`{}`) above for correct formatting.

is the exact same subset of users who will actually check the rendered preview below their question before submission to ensure that their question is readable. Or, failing that, they'll at least notice after they submit the question, and use the "edit" link to fix the problem.

[We already provide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118230/better-help-text-for-formatting-code) [plenty of help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92668/is-there-a-way-to-improve-new-user-code-formatting-in-questions-and-answers) to users regarding how to use the existing code formatting tools, so those people who *want* to get this right *will*.

The rest, well, you'll either have to edit, [nag](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116), or ignore.

Comment: I disagree with *"We already provide plenty of help"*, a new user don't know about the meta site. I'm a very meticulous person, I care a lot about formatting, but the first time I couldn't get it right, the help message (simple and advanced) under `Code` it's just not complete enough imo, it just tells to use 4 spaces, but not of the shortcut or about the `{}` button for multiline. I think I'll open a question to discuss an improvement to the code help.

Comment: @The Establishment, I disagree with your assessment. You're right that these users are looking at the preview. _That's the problem_. They're looking at the preview and seeing that their code looks wrong, and then "fixing" it in a lazy way. Unless there's an attention-grabbing message telling them about a better way, they'll keep doing this. See my edit above for my line of reasoning.

Comment: @Rik: The point of those links wasn't that new users would refer to them, it was to provide a description of the help that we already *do* provide for new users. The *content* of the answers is what matters, not the mere fact of their existence.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Ah ok, but I don't think anyway that the help is good enough. I [opened a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127215/177799) a couple of hours ago, to explain what I'd like to see in the help.