# Automatic code formatting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

I am a frequent user of StackOverflow. Many beginner questions contain code that has no formatting at all, some even close to winning a code obfuscation contest. I try to answer even beginner questions, and what I end up doing is just copying the code snippet, pasting it into my favorite IDE/editor, format it, then paste it back and edit the question.

What I'd very much like to see is an automatic code formatting feature on the site. Is it so hard to implement one? Are there reasons for not implementing it? (I.e., lack of time/resources/other motives)?

For example, implementing a plugin similar to [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), at least for common languages.

Comment: Also related: [Format as code automatically when pressing `Ctrl+K` or clicking on { } at the begining of a line](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88108/format-as-code-automatically-when-pressing-ctrlk-or-clicking-on-at-the-be?rq=1)

Comment: @MatthewHaugen thanks for pointing out the dupe, unfortunately the feature is still very "primitive" And the second question doesn't even have any comments/answers :)

Comment: Also also related (on meta.SO): [Let's have a “Tidy Up” button!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261249/lets-have-a-tidy-up-button)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus yes, similar indeed. Unfortunately I didn't find these duplicates, and am a bit surprised people downvoted my question. I find this issue extremely important, my question is not stupid (at least that's what I think), and I'd just like to find out an answer from some SE admin/developer what's the reason for not implementing such a feature. I try to contribute as much as possible to StackOverflow (primarily in the C++ tag), and am really annoyed by super-badly formatted code.

Comment: "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself" — http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus my bad then. Although frankly I cannot imagine someone who's not bother by this issue :)